# Does BLS aggregating signatures allow duplicate signatures?

Tags: bls-signature

If there is a message $m_1$ that $H(m_1) \rightarrow g^r$
and there is another message $m_2$ that $H(m_2) \rightarrow g^k$, where $g^k$ is also a generator of $G$, is this possible?
then $g^r$ could equal $(g^k)^m$, where $m < p$, $p$ is the order of $G$.
Then any message could be expressed in this form $(g^k)^m$, so if we allow aggregating duplicate messages from one same signer, it is not safe in BLS?

Comment: Then any message could be expressed in this form (g^k)^m    Is this hard for us to find the m? This is the assumption of Discrete logarithm Problem.

Comment: Welcome to CryptoGraphy. We have $LaTeX / MathJax $ enabled in [our site](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/using-mathjax-tex-on-the-cryptography-site).

Comment: @ray_james could you turn your comment into an answer?